# roboearth no models?

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to use the roboearth stack. However, when trying to download the test model I get a "410 GONE". Are there available models to test with ? Or do I have to build one ?

Best regards,

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11205/roboearth-no-models-?/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guido,

to see the object models available in the database, please take a look at the [web interface](http://api.roboearth.org/objects/request): click on the upper "Search" button without entering anything to see all object models.

Also, if you want to test the recognition algorithm, try downloading the "videogames.kinectadventures" model (this is the model from the video).

HTH,
Daniel

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-09-14**:
Really nice, thank you.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-12-08**:
I upload one object now but do not know how to download it into knowrob and what is the OWL description which created automatic be used for ?!!
can u help me about this ?!